# How to get both date and time in a single dialog box

Tags: android

I am using following code to pick date, however i wanted to pick the date as well as time (in a single dialog box)...

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener beginDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
            setBeginDateOnView();
        }
    };

 public void beginDateOnClick(View view) {
        new DatePickerDialog(CreateEventActivity.this,beginDate,c.get(Calendar.YEAR),c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }

  public void setBeginDateOnView() {
        String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault());
        edtBeginDate.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in "date and time picker in one" solution for Android, so you'll have to combine a DatePicker and a TimePicker into a dialog by yourself, or use a library that does it.

For a library, i can suggest using [SlideDateTimePicker](https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker), i used it in a project a while back and it works well.

Or you can write your own, by simply creating a new class that extends AlertDialog, setting up 2 tabs inside it and then setting the tabs to include a DatePicker and a TimePicker.

Comment: SlideDateTimePicker its being old nowadays, Can you have any idea about material dialog pickers? please share if you have. Thank you.